# Is it possbile for a ninja to have larger chakra supply by training?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto we know that many Ninjas have different chakra supply. So by that every ninja varies from each other by the amount of chakra supply they have.

So my question is that, Is it possible for someone to have larger chakra supply by doing training, I mean by having intense training is it possible that any ninja can increase their chakra supply or it comes naturally by birth with fixed amount?

Comment: Well, I think its a bit of both, but if you can dominate nature chakra well, that's a pretty immense chakra supply.

Comment: The wikia says yes, but I don't know where they got that information. I recall them talking about it when Naruto was training with Kakashi. And maybe when Choji first went butterfly mode?

Comment: You can but there is a cap on how much you can increase your supply. For instance when Naruto is training with Kakashi and even when he fights reincarnated Zabuza he says "I don't have as much chakra as you". Characters with tailed beasts have a damn near endless supply because the creatures they have in them have damn near limitless supplies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the chakra supply for each individual can grow through training. But will be limited by genetics.

Let's take a look at what chakra is.

> Chakra is created when two other forms of energy, known collectively as one's "stamina", are molded together. ~ [Naruto-wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra)

With the first form being `Physical energy (身体エネルギー, shintai enerugī)` and the second one being `Spiritual energy (精神エネルギー, seishin enerugī)`

By training ones Physical body and Mental strength, the chakra pool can be increased.

Genetics however does play a mayor role. As some people, such as Naruto for example, just have a very large pool from the get go. And even with a lot of training, somebody like Ino would never be able to reach the same chakra pool size.

This limit is best observed with Rock Lee, as his genetics limited his growth on Spiritual energy, he tries to overcome it through Physical energy.

It is also possible to indirectly improve one's chakra pool, through [Chakra control](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra#Chakra_Control). It does not directly expand the chakra pool itself, but allows for a user to do more with the same amount of chakra.